# Full Memory Dump missing stack information

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, cpu-usage, dump

I'm attempting to debug a high CPU issue from a customer. I've tried having them use procdump, however, it hangs while writing the dump without ever finishing. Instead the customer has initiated a complete memory dump using the keyboard when the CPU levels spike.

I'd like to be able to see the stack trace for all the process' threads, but I'm not able to see any more than the top 4-6 stack frames for any one thread. This frustrating as these frames only contain the trap routines initiated by the bugcheck. I'm new to WinDbg so I'm not sure how to gather this information. I'm getting the stack information by doing the following:

```
2: kd> !process 0 0 process.exe
PROCESS 8997f590  SessionId: 0  Cid: 094c    Peb: 7ffd6000  ParentCid: 01c4
DirBase: 503f1000  ObjectTable: e53f1880  HandleCount: 1924.
Image: process.exe
2: kd> !process 8997f590
PROCESS 8997f590  SessionId: 0  Cid: 094c    Peb: 7ffd6000  ParentCid: 01c4
DirBase: 503f1000  ObjectTable: e53f1880  HandleCount: 1924.
[...]
THREAD 89daf4f0  Cid 094c.0950  Teb: 7ffdf000 Win32Thread: e53f1ae0 WAIT: (Unknown) UserMode Non-Alertable
8997f8ac  NotificationEvent
[...]
ChildEBP RetAddr  
    b8cf9c04 8083d26e nt!KiSwapContext+0x26 (FPO: [Uses EBP] [0,0,4])
    b8cf9c30 8083dc5e nt!KiSwapThread+0x2e5 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    b8cf9c78 809208d7 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x346 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    b8cf9ca0 8093aef7 nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x180 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    b8cf9d38 8083387f nt!NtReadFile+0x5d5 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    b8cf9d38 7c82847c nt!KiFastCallEntry+0xfc (FPO: [0,0] TrapFrame @ b8cf9d64)
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
    0012fc58 00000000 0x7c82847c
[...]
```

If I switch to any thread's context and run, for instance, `kb 50` I'll still only get the top several frames. Is there anyway to get the rest of the call stack? Could this information be unavailable if it was paged to disk?

Also, any tips on how to debug high CPU usage would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
!process 8997f590 1f
```

The issue that you're having is described in this article:

http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=576

Basically, a full memory dump contains many different process contexts. In order to see user mode state, you need to make sure that the debugger is using the correct process context (which the 0x10 flag will do in this case).

In terms of debugging high CPU utilization, !process 0 1 will show user and kernel CPU times for each process. If a particular set of processes are spiking it should be clear from the output. A better alternative for tracking this down however is probably xperf, which will sample the CPU over a period of time (instead of just looking at a snapshot in time, like you are here).

-scott